# Do we have to say "Uhr" when we give the time?

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, phrase-request, time

I just can't tell if it's dropped because it's a list of how to say different times and the creator of it just didn't care, or if that's actually fine when providing the time.

Question:

> Wie spät ist es?

Answer 1:

> Es ist fünf vor halb drei

Answer 2:

> fünf vor halb drei

**without** "es ist"?

Comment: I don't see the connection between your text and the title. You might want to edit one or both of them to make your question clearer. Right now I have no idea what you want to know and how you could be helped therefore.

Comment: @bakunin: Then you should vote to close the question upon improvement, more details and clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking two different questions, so I'll try to answer both of them.

Regarding "Uhr", there are two different situations:

> "Es ist drei [Uhr]."

With full hours, "Uhr" is generally used, but can be omitted in colloquial speech if it's clear we're talking about time.

> "Es ist viertel vor drei."

Using "Uhr" would be wrong. That's true for all time designations differing from a full hour.

Regarding "Es ist": if you're answering a question, it's your stylistic choice whether to use a complete sentence or just give the information that was asked for, like in

> Welche Farbe hat das Auto? [Es ist] schwarz.

Comment: "Viertel vor drei Uhr" is not wrong, just extremely uncommon.

Comment: In colloquial speech even more can be left out: Q: "Wie spät ist es?" A: "Viertel vor." The answer is valid if it is clear which hour it is.

Comment: @Roland "Viertel vor drei Uhr" is so uncommon that I never heard it in all my 60+ yrs of life.

Comment: @Roland If somebody says "viertel vor drei Uhr" as a German language learner,  it will be understood as them not knowing better, a.k.a. seen as wrong.

Comment: „Nachts um halb drei Uhr“ or similar is perfectly fine, if uncommon. As a learner of German it's probably best to leave it out.

Comment: @HalvarF Everybody will understand it, thus one cannot say it is wrong.  Also see https://www.google.com/search?q=%22viertel+vor+drei+Uhr%22&client=firefox-b-d&ei=wLWrYv7IKsPzkgWo-bPIDw&ved=0ahUKEwj-qM6wibP4AhXDuaQKHaj8DPkQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22viertel+vor+drei+Uhr%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWOgUIABCABDoECAAQHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWN4UYJ4YaABwAXgAgAFAiAG7AZIBATOYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz.

Comment: @PaulFrost That argument doesn't work because well-formedness does not imply understandability, nor vice versa. - More to the point: Please don't explain to learners that don't even know how to tell the time yet that something is "possible but uncommon, not wrong at all"; tell them what they need to know, i.e. how to tell the time as a native speaker would.

Comment: Also that Google search includes advice such as: *Machen Sie deutlich, dass man bei der Angabe der inoffiziellen Uhrzeit nur bis zwölf zählt und man nicht „Viertel vor drei Uhr“ sagt, sondern nur „Viertel vor drei“.* Which I support whole-heartedly.

Answer (score 1):

giving the time is a very complex topic. It's a matter of where you are in the D-A-CH area. In Austria we mostly use Viertel and Dreiviertel of an hour if you don't want to tell the exact time. If you use "Es ist" or not, is a matter of how much time you want to spend to tell the time.

Examples:

8h15: Viertel Neun
8h30: Halb Neun
8h45: Dreiviertel Neun

In most parts of Germany you will hear:

8h15: Viertel nach Acht
8h30: Halb Neun
8h45: Viertel Vor Neun

Try it and have fun!

Comment: That 's really not an answer to the question, though, is it?